# Multi step registration form fields not being saved

Tags: 7, users, forms

The user accounts have been extended with many fields.

I built a custom module which converts the registration form into a multi-page form.

In `hook_register_validate` I compile all the values from across the pages into `$form_state['values']`. Dumping this array shows that all the values are present

Then in my submit handler I do this:

```
function MYMODULE_register_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Clean values
    form_state_values_clean($form_state);

    // Save initial email
    $form_state['values']['init'] = $form_state['values']['mail'];

    // Build a user from the form state values
    $account = $form['#user'];
    entity_form_submit_build_entity('user', $account, $form, $form_state);

    $account = user_save($account);
}
```

The account is created, but for some reason the majority of the fields are missing!

They go missing after the `entity_form_submit_build_entity` call even though they are present in `$form_state['values']`.

All of the text fields are being saved, but none of the select or checkboxes. Also, the profile picture is saved but none of the other files.

Comment: To create multistep form, you should use $form_state['storage']  property of the $form+_state to store the value and fetch into next step.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola That's true for Drupal 6, not for Drupal 7.

Comment: @Clive, but we can use the same logic for the Drupal 7 also.